# Django - How to set default ForeignKey value for ModelForm without allowing user input

Tags: django, foreign-keys, modelform

I've built a little app with models `Page` and `Mark`.

`Mark` also has a `ModelForm` class `MarkForm`, which I've told to display all of its attributes as widgets, except `ForeignKey`, which is `editable=False`. There's a one-to-many relationship between `Page` and `Mark` - one `Page`, many `Marks`.

When I try to submit the `MarkForm`, however, it nags that the `ForeignKey` field cannot be blank - is there a way to tell the form automatically (on the server side), that , so that there won't be a form output in the html (I don't want users to be able to fiddle and add `marks` to other `Pages`).

If I'm missing something, please let me know, maybe I've done something wrong in my models or views. Here's some code:

```
class Mark(models.Model):
    page  = models.ForeignKey(Page, editable=False)
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MarkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mark
        widgets = {
            'x': HiddenInput(),
            'y': HiddenInput(),
            'width': HiddenInput(),
            'height': HiddenInput(),
            'body': HiddenInput(),
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude a field, you can [do it in the ModelForm's Meta class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form).

To pre-set a field value, you could do in the view, e.g.:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MarkForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.page = myid
            obj.save()
```

Comment: It's giving me this: `Cannot assign "1": "Mark.page" must be a "Page" instance.`

Comment: Well, then give him a page instance. obj.page = Page.objects.get(id=1)

Comment: And what if the `page` field is not null in the model? The `is_valid()` call is going to fail, am I right? So, how can I proceed?